# Should pthread program take longer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Maybe I’m confusing myself with threads, but my understanding of threading conflicts with each other.

I’ve created a program which uses POSIX `pthread`s. Without using these threads the program takes 0.061723 seconds to run, and with threads takes 0.081061 seconds to run.

At first I thought this is what should happen, as threads allow something to happen while other things should be able to happen. i.e. processing a lot of data on one thread while still having responsive UI on another, this would mean the processing of the data would take longer as the CPU divides its time between processing UI and processing the data.

However, surely the point of multithreading is to make the program take advantage of multiple CPUs/cores?

As you can tell I’m something of an intermediate so excuse me if it’s a simple question.

But what should I expect the program to do?

I’m running this on a mid-2012 Macbook Pro 13” base model. CPU is 22 nm "Ivy Bridge" 2.5 GHz Intel "Core i5" processor (3210M), with two independent processor "cores" on a single silicon chip

***UPDATED WITH CODE***

This is in main function. I didn’t add variable declaration for convenience but I’m sure you can work out what each does by its name:

```
//          Loop through all items we need to process
//
while (totalNumberOfItemsToProcess > 0 && numberOfItemsToProcessOnEachIteration > 0 && startingIndex <= totalNumberOfItemsToProcess)
{
    //  As long as we have items to process...
    //
    //      Align the index with number of items to process per iteration
    //
    const uint endIndex = startingIndex + (numberOfItemsToProcessOnEachIteration - 1);

    //  Create range
    //
    Range range = RangeMake(startingIndex,
                            endIndex);

    rangesProcessed[i] = range;

    //  Create thread
    //
    //      Create a thread identifier, 'newThread'
    //
    pthread_t newThread;

    //      Create thread with range
    //
    int threadStatus = pthread_create(&newThread, NULL, processCoordinatesInRangePointer, &rangesProcessed[i]);

    if (threadStatus != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create thread" << std::endl;

        exit(1);
    }

    //  Add thread to threads
    //
    threadIDs.push_back(newThread);

    //  Setup next iteration
    //
    //      Starting index
    //
    //          Realign the index with number of items to process per iteration
    //
    startingIndex = (endIndex + 1);

    //      Number of items to process on each iteration
    //
    if (startingIndex > (totalNumberOfItemsToProcess - numberOfItemsToProcessOnEachIteration))
    {
        //  If the total number of items to process is less than the number of items to process on each iteration
        //
        numberOfItemsToProcessOnEachIteration = totalNumberOfItemsToProcess - startingIndex;
    }

    //  Increment index
    //
    i++;
}

std::cout << "Number of threads: " << threadIDs.size() << std::endl;

//          Loop through all threads, rejoining them back up
//
for ( size_t i = 0;
      i < threadIDs.size();
      i++ )
{
    //      Wait for each thread to finish before returning
    //
    pthread_t currentThreadID = threadIDs[i];

    int joinStatus = pthread_join(currentThreadID, NULL);

    if (joinStatus != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Thread join failed" << std::endl;

        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The processing functions:

```
void processCoordinatesAtIndex(uint index)
{
    const int previousIndex = (index - 1);

    //  Get coordinates from terrain
    //
    Coordinate3D previousCoordinate = terrain[previousIndex];
    Coordinate3D currentCoordinate = terrain[index];

    //  Calculate...
    //
    //      Euclidean distance
    //
    double euclideanDistance = Coordinate3DEuclideanDistanceBetweenPoints(previousCoordinate, currentCoordinate);

    euclideanDistances[index] = euclideanDistance;

    //      Angle of slope
    //
    double slopeAngle = Coordinate3DAngleOfSlopeBetweenPoints(previousCoordinate, currentCoordinate, false);

    slopeAngles[index] = slopeAngle;
}

void processCoordinatesInRange(Range range)
{
    for ( uint i = range.min;
          i <= range.max;
          i++ )
    {
        processCoordinatesAtIndex(i);
    }
}

void *processCoordinatesInRangePointer(void *threadID)
{
    //  Cast the pointer to the right type
    //
    struct Range *range = (struct Range *)threadID;

    processCoordinatesInRange(*range);

    return NULL;
}
```

UPDATE:

Here are my global variables, which, are only global for simplicity - don’t have a go!

```
std::vector<Coordinate3D> terrain;

std::vector<double> euclideanDistances;
std::vector<double> slopeAngles;

std::vector<Range> rangesProcessed;

std::vector<pthread_t> threadIDs;
```

Comment: In which way are you using threads to speed up the program? Details matter. Spawning threads has an overhead.

Comment: I have ten threads, each thread takes a range of data from an array of coordinates. Then performs calculations on those values. i.e thread0 takes indexes 0-29,999. thread1 takes indexes 30,000-59,999 etc

Comment: @AdamCarter In fact introducing multithreading the wrong way, it can slow down your program actually. Hard to tell.

Comment: First and foremost, concurrency imposes a heavy *cost* on your execution because data synchronization forces all participants to stall. Concurrency is only useful if you can actually do enough work independently and concurrently that the runtime improvements outweigh the synchronisation costs. This is definitely not easy.

Comment: Code speaks *volumes* when it comes to threading. For all we know you're synchronously chaining your threads (you'd be amazed how often people stuff a `thrds[i].join();` in the very loop that is launching their threads). *Post your code* (at least the threading architecture and data partitioning).

Comment: @KerrekSB, At the moment the array consists of 150,000 values each with an array of 3 values. Are you suggesting it be best if I add more values? I’ll try this and get back

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, I did this originally and realised the mistake. Time above is from a program that doesn’t do that. Should @KerrekSB’s solution fail i’ll post code

Comment: @AdamCarter: I suppose I'd rather suggest that you analyse the work efficiency of your concurrent algorithm and estimate the synchronization cost. An algorithmic analysis is more robust than trying some random inputs.

Comment: @AdamCarter while you're at it, don't bother kicking off more than `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` threads unless your program is IO-bound (which it is *not* by the sound of it, so anything more than that is likely introducing more hardware contention than you need).

Comment: how do you measure time?

Comment: @Micka, A `clock_t startTime = clock();` goes before the while loop, and a similar `clock_t endTime = clock();` goes after the `pthread_join` for loop. `clock_t totalTime = endTime - startTime;` is calculated then output with `std::to_string( (double)totalTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC )`

Comment: @AdamCarter: yes, I meant something like the link you provided (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/). But this should not really be an issue. Since your output `euclideanDistances and slopeAngless` ara most probably plain arrays (and no some intelligent thread-safe versions of std::vector or other container), there are no locks inside that would kill the performance.. I removed my post after noticing that.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yeah, their 1D arrays in a global scope so I didn’t see how it would have been different either. I’d be grateful for any other ideas. Thanks so far.

Comment: @AdamCarter `clock()` doesnt work as you'd expect with multi threading, because it measures the CPU TIME, which sums up the times used active on all processors by all threads, afaik. What you really want to do is measure the real time duration.

Comment: @Micka Ah, there was some deliberation when coding whether to use `clock()` or the wall time. I’m guessing the alternative you’re implying is the wall time, do you have a brief summary of the difference?

Comment: examples: Assume a scenario where there is no overhead in creating or synchronozing threads. Assume a task that is finished by a single thread in 100 seconds, but is perfectly parallelizable, so if you add a second thread, each one can perform its part of the work in 50 seconds, 4 threads will need 25 seconds each and so on. So you have 4 processors (the 4 threads can work in parallel), the full task will need 25 seconds wall time instead of 100 seconds. But each of those threads has needed 25 seconds on its processor, so the CPU time is still 100 seconds.

Comment: on the other hand, if you measure wall time, you start your program and some other program starts some critical threads using all the CPU sources, your Wall time will count even though your program isnt processed at all, ending in a bigger wall time, but your CPU time will still be 100 ;)

Comment: @Micka I understand what you’re saying, but neither examples really help me in processing the accurate time taken. Or are you saying that it’s impossible to measure time given the fact both clock_t and wall time have their pros/cons?

Comment: in fact, wall time is the time taken from the beginning of your processing to the end of your processing, but that might include different things, like if you're waiting for user input etc. cpu time is more like needed ressources than actual "time duration" (in real world time meaning). So depending on what you want to measure, you'll have to use wall or cpu time. For multi-threading, cpu time will increase in all real world examples, since you get some overhead in creating and synchronizing threads. If you want to measure the difference between 2 single threaded algorithms, use cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I’m wrong, but, I think the issue was with how the time elapsed was measured. Instead of using `clock_t` I’ve moved to `gettimeofday()` and that reports a shorter time, from non threaded time of `22.629000 ms` to a threaded time of `8.599000 ms`.

Does this seem right to people?

Of course, my original question was based on whether or not a multithreaded program SHOULD be faster or not, so I won’t mark this answer as the correct one for that reason.

Comment: if you execute a multi-threaded program on a single core sytem, it will probably run slower than for the same task to be performed on a single-threaded program.

Comment: The specs of my computer (in my question) say two cores on one chip, therefore shouldn’t the multithreaded one be faster?

Comment: speedup from 22.629000 ms to 8.599000 ms is faster, isn't it? Obviously, the amount of work is still the same, so the CPU time doesn't reduce. Since there is some overhead for creating and synchronizing threads, CPU time even increases slightly.

Comment: Ok, so the best method of measuring time elapsed in my scenario, is wall time? right?

Comment: if it is possible to find out, how many processors in average are used in parallel for that processing, you could use clock and divide it by the number of average used threads, but I dont know a way to measure that. Maybe with profiling tools like `Valgrind`